# Using Contains with a regex on input[type="submit"]

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress to test a form which has an `input` of `type="submit"`. When I select the element with

```js
cy.contains('Submit new data')
```

it works, but when I use a regex

```js
cy.contains(/Submit new data/)
```

I get error expected to find content: '/Save Changes/'.

Can anyone help me, what is the problem with using regex in `.contains()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/21166), but has been fixed in the latest release Cypress v10.3.1 (Released 7/19/2022).

> **Current behavior**
>
> ```js
> <form>
>   <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
> </form>
>
> cy.contains('Save Changes') // OK. yields input[type='submit'] element
> cy.contains(/Save Changes/) // ERROR. Expected to find content: '/Save Changes/'
> ```

If you have an older version of Cypress, please upgrade and try the same test again.